# SDL Web 8 free developer licenses

Tags: web8

I came to know that SDL will be rolling out Web 8 with free developer licenses.
If that's true, does anyone know how and where to apply for the developer license? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

This will roll out in the coming 3/4 weeks (before end of November) on community.sdl.com. Rest assured, we'll make enough noise around that, you'll find it easily.

These will be your typical "free research" licenses, issued to individuals that want to learn the software, it's for ***non-commercial*** use, etc.

**EDIT**
I've started an [FAQ on Meta](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403/faq-whats-this-developer-license-for/).

Comment: Not sure if licences are still available?
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Lalit Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange. I have converted your answer to a comment as it did not answer the question. I hazard a guess and say that the licences are probably coming in the next few weeks since the software came out yesterday. Keep an eye on Twitter, here and http://community.sdl.com

Comment: We hit a bit of a snag deploying the form to http://community.sdl.com - keeping up with my promise, send an email to sdl.tridion.mvp@sdl.com and I'll sort you out

Comment: Very important part "non-commercial" -- so can not be used for customer projects!